# Filtering a table in Shiny based on clicking on chart

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm currently trying to filter the data in a table based on the observation I click on in a Plotly chart.

Currently I have tried using different combinations of observeEvent and eventRegister with no success and have also tried to replicate the logic presented in example 17.25 here: https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html#advanced-applications.  A sample of my server code is shown below:

```
server = function(input, output, session) {

weight = reactiveValues()
observeEvent(event_data("plotly_click", source = "weight"), {
weight(event_data("plotly_click", source = "weight")$y)
})

output$weight = renderPlotly({
plot_ly(data = dataset1(), x = ~n, y = ~ percent_weight_change, source = "weight") |> event_register("plotly_click")
})

output$weight_loss = renderDataTable({
select(dataset2(), person_id, percent_weight_change) |>
filter(percent_weight_change == weight())
```

Comment: {crosstalk} with its concept of `SharedData` between widgets might be helpful: https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/, https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/using.html